# Max-heap (insert and delete)

Tags: algorithm, heap

In max-heap, suppose that a person calls `insert()` with an item that is larger than all items in the heap, and then immediately calls `deleteMax()`. Assume that there are no duplicate keys. is the resulting heap identical to the heap as it was before these operations?

**My answer:** Insert max element in the heap takes `O(log n)` and delete max also takes `O(log n)`. So, the new insert element will be the in the root, and the old max element (which was at the root) will delete.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Just for clarity, the question includes that insert() is not blocking and deleteMax() is called before insert() finishes?

Comment: Reverted your edit - an answer without a question is meaningless. Why would you remove the question?

Comment: This also assumes a binary heap. Something like a Pairing heap or a Fibonacci heap could have a vastly different internal state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new heap will exactly be the same as the original one **if there are no duplicates**.

This is because when you add a large element, it initially gets added as a leaf and it bubbles up to the top. **It does so by continuously swapping the original parent (originally larger node) element with itself**.

Now when you deleteMax(), the root is emptied (or filled with last node of the tree). So the **larger** child takes its place. This larger child was the original root of the tree. Hence bubbling down happens as per the same path as bubbling up.

**If there are duplicates, then on deletion, either of the children can take the empty root's position. Hence it is not guaranteed that the final tree would be the same.**

For example with no duplicates,

Original tree:

```
       10
     7    6
   4
.
```

Add 11:

```
       10
     7    6
   4  11
.
       10
     11    6
   4   7
.
       11
     10   6
   4   7
.
```

Now deleteMax():

```
       _
    10   6
  4   7
.
       10
     _    6
   4   7
.
       10
     7    6
   4
.
```

Or as other implementation of deleteMax() suggested by @CaptainCodeman:

```
       7
    10   6
  4   
.
       10
     7    6
   4   
.
```

With duplicates:

Original tree:

```
       10
     7    10
   4
.
```

Add 11:

```
       10
     7    10
   4  11
.
       10
     11    10
   4   7
.
       11
     10   10
   4   7
.
```

Now deleteMax():

```
       _
    10   10
  4   7
.
       10
     10   _  // the right child can also take its place
   4   7
.
```

Or as other implementation of deleteMax() suggested by @CaptainCodeman:

```
       7
    10   10
  4   
.
       10
     10    7 // the right child can also take its place
   4   
.
```

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is true, as there is more than one way to implement deleteMax.  For example, some implementations take an element from the bottom of the tree and put it at the root, and then swap it down.  (Rather than swapping down an empty space)

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Even then the tree will result in its original orientation. I'll update my answer.